# Get profile picture from set user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking to get my bot to reply to my command with a hard-coded user's profile picture.

This is the code I have for now, as it is it replies with the message.author's pfp and I'm wondering if and how I could replace the `user = message.author`
for it to target a hard-coded user.

```
if message.content.upper().startswith('TEST'):
userID = message.author.id
user = message.author
pfp = user.avatar_url
embed = discord.Embed(
  title="test",
  description='<@%s>, test' % (userID),
  color=0xecce8b
)
embed.set_image(url=pfp)

await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed) `
```

I also know that if I switch to "for user in message.mentions" I can get it to pop out the mentioned user's pfp, but again, I want to be able to do this without mentioning anyone.

Thank you for your time and any answers brought forward!

Comment: What do you mean by `pfp`?  I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: my bad, it stands for "profile picture" aka : "avatar"

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Comment: For cheesy reasons x:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Server.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.get_member) to resolve the `Member` whom you have the id for.

```
if message.content.upper().startswith('TEST'):
    user = message.server.get_member("116273596605049942") # Fake snowflake, will not work
    if not user:
        return # Can't find the user, then quit
    pfp = user.avatar_url
    embed=discord.Embed(title="test", description='{}, test'.format(user.mention) , color=0xecce8b)
    embed.set_image(url=(pfp))
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is for discord rewrite working as of ***1.5.1***

```
author = ctx.message.author
pfp = author.avatar_url
```