# How to make discord.py bot pull mentioned user's profile picture with a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make my botpull mentioned user's profile picture with a command like "!pfp @user"

Due to my lacking knowledge in python and discord bots in general i tried many ways but i still didn't succeed on impelementing this feature.

here is the current code that i want to implement this feature into:

bot.py

```
import discord
import responses
import requests
async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = ''
    WEATHER_API_KEY = ''


    intents = discord.Intents.all()

    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
    


    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running')


    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: {user_message} ({channel})')

        if user_message.startswith('?'):
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)
     # Check if the message author is a bot

        if '@everyone' in message.content:
            
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, don't ping everyone")
            # You can also delete the message that contains @everyone if needed
            # await message.delete(del_message)     

        if 'önemli' in user_message:
            if message.mentions:
                mentioned_user=message.mentions[0]
                if mentioned_user!=client.user:
                    await mentioned_user.send(f'{message.author} said {message.content}')
    
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!hava'):
            city = message.content.split(' ', 1)[1]  # Get the city name from the command
            weather_data = get_weather(city)

            if weather_data:
                embed = create_weather_embed(city, weather_data)
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await message.channel.send("Şehir bulunamadı ya da API hatası var.")

    def get_weather(city):
        base_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
        params = {
            'q': city,
            'appid': WEATHER_API_KEY,
            'units': 'metric'  # You can change the units to imperial if needed
        }

        responsee = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
        if responsee.status_code == 200:
            return responsee.json()
        else:
            return None

    def create_weather_embed(city, data):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{city} şehrinde hava durumu:", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Hava Durumu", value=data['weather'][0]['description'], inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Sıcaklık", value=f"{data['main']['temp']}°C", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Hissedilen Sıcaklık", value=f"{data['main']['feels_like']}°C", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Bulutlar", value=f"{data['clouds']['all']}%", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Nem Oranı", value=f"{data['main']['humidity']}%", inline=True)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{data['weather'][0]['icon']}.png")

        return embed    



    client.run(TOKEN)
```

I don't know how to use @client.command() or @bot.event() properly so i put codes into the same section i believe if there is a way to avoid that the code will work cleaner but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: maybe first learn how to use `@client.command()` - ie. `@client.command() async def pfp(ctx): ...`, or `@client.command(name="pfp") async def any_name(ctx): ...`,

Comment: [python - Get profile picture from set user - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423859/get-profile-picture-from-set-user)

Comment: BTW: you may have to check in documentation if `discord` allow to get image of user - it may restrict it to users which you know or which are on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your on_message function

```
  if message.content.startswith('!pfp'):
        if len(message.mentions) > 0:
            user = message.mentions[0]
            pfp_url = user.avatar.url
            await message.channel.send(pfp_url)
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Please mention a user")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**